# Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked still occuring even after adding RxImmediateSchedulerRule

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java2, android-looper

TrendingViewModelTest

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class TrendingViewModelTest {
    private lateinit var trendingRepository: TrendingRepository
    private lateinit var trendingViewModel: TrendingViewModel

    @get:Rule
    val schedulers = RxImmediateSchedulerRule()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        trendingRepository = mock(TrendingRepository::class.java)
        trendingViewModel = TrendingViewModel(trendingRepository)
    }

    @Test
    fun testWithNetwork() {
        trendingViewModel.isConnected = true
        trendingViewModel.fetchTrendingRepos()
        verify(trendingRepository, times(1)).getTrendingRepos()
    }

    //...
}
```

TrendingViewModel

```
fun fetchTrendingRepos() {
if (isConnected) {
    loadingProgress.value = true
    compositeDisposable.add(
        trendingRepository.getTrendingRepos().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ response ->
                run {
                    loadingProgress.value = false
            },
                { error ->
                    loadingProgress.value = false
                }
            )
    )
}
```

RxImmediateSchedulerRule:

```
class RxImmediateSchedulerRule : TestRule {
    override fun apply(base: Statement?, description: Description?): Statement {
        return object : Statement() {
            @Throws(Throwable::class)
            override fun evaluate() {
                RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
                RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
                RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
                RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }

                try {
                    base?.evaluate()
                } finally {
                    RxJavaPlugins.reset()
                    RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TrendingRepositoryImpl:

```
class TrendingRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    val apiService: GitHubApi,
    val trendingDao: AppDao
) : TrendingRepository {

    override fun getTrendingRepos(): Single<List<TrendingRepo>> {
        return apiService.getTrendingGits()
    }
}
```

TrendingRepository:

```
interface TrendingRepository {
    fun getTrendingRepos(): Single<List<TrendingRepo>>
}
```

Inside `fetchTrendingRepos()` an Rxjava call is initiated, it also hooks onto 'AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()' that might be the reason causing it.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked.
>   at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java)
>       at androidx.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor.isMainThread(DefaultTaskExecutor.java:77)
>       at androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor.isMainThread(ArchTaskExecutor.java:116)
>       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.assertMainThread(LiveData.java:461)
>       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:304)
>       at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
>       at com.manoj.trendgitz.mvvm.ui.TrendingViewModel.fetchTrendingRepos(TrendingViewModel.kt:32)
>       at com.manoj.trendgitz.TrendingViewModelTest.testWithNetwork(TrendingViewModelTest.kt:52)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Comment: Can you put all the logs that you get when you run the test?

Comment: Added that @NatigBabayev

Answer (score 68, accepted):

As you update `LiveData` value, you should add `@get:Rule var rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()` also.

Don't forget to add following to **build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
}
```

Also, change your test code accordingly to avoid `NullPointerException`:

```
@Test
fun testWithNetwork() {
    trendingViewModel.isConnected = true
    Mockito.`when`(trendingRepository.fetchTrendingRepos()).thenReturn(Single.just(listOf<TrendingRepo>()))
    trendingViewModel.fetchTrendingRepos()
    verify(trendingRepository, times(1)).getTrendingRepos()
}
```

`Mockito.when()` lets you to do different actions every time your mock method is called. If you don't use it, you may see possible `NullPointerException` depending on your test function.

Comment: It's causing java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.manoj.trendgitz.mvvm.ui.TrendingViewModel.fetchTrendingRepos(TrendingViewModel.kt:34)
 at com.manoj.trendgitz.TrendingViewModelTest.testWithNetwork(TrendingViewModelTest.kt:53) @Natig Babayev

Comment: What is in 34th line of TrendingViewModel?

Comment: trendingRepository.getTrendingRepos().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), I debugged that too, it's not null

Comment: Probably, you're missing ```Mockito.`when`(trendingRepository.fetchTrendingRepos()).thenReturn(...)```. Add it before viewModel function call.

Comment: updated the question a little bit too @Natig Babayev

Comment: Just what i needed, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Add the below lines under android {} in your app's build.gradle

```
testOptions {
            // Used for Unit testing Android dependent elements in /test folder
            unitTests.includeAndroidResources  = true
            unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        }
```

Comment: Rerun all tests after adding this. There may be unexpected failures.

Answer (score 9):

First add `testImplementation` for `core-testing`.

```
testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
```

Then in your unit test class add an `InstantTaskExecutorRule` at variable `rule`.

```
import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule

class TrendingViewModelTest {

     @get:Rule
     val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It case you are seeing this error without adding `RxImmediateSchedulerRule`. Try to add this rule to your test class:

```
@Rule @JvmField
val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```