# JUnit 5 testing not working with activities

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to use JUnit 5 to test a function inside of an activity in Android Studio using Java, however, I am getting the following error:

```
Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
    at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java)
    at androidx.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor.isMainThread(DefaultTaskExecutor.java:77)
    at androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor.isMainThread(ArchTaskExecutor.java:116)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.enforceMainThreadIfNeeded(LifecycleRegistry.java:316)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:172)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.<init>(ComponentActivity.java:244)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:103)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:94)
    at com.dhaini.passpall.InstructorAddTaskToStudentToDoListActivity.<init>(InstructorAddTaskToStudentToDoListActivity.java:38)
    at com.dhaini.passpall.InstructorAddTaskToStudentToDoListActivityTest.getRandomInteger(InstructorAddTaskToStudentToDoListActivityTest.java:19)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

I am following online tutorials, but none of them are implementing testing on activities, instead they are simple classes within main.

This is my test code:

```
package com.dhaini.passpall;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class InstructorAddTaskToStudentToDoListActivityTest {

    @Test
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Test
    public void buildRecyclerView() {
    }

    @Test
    public void getRandomInteger() {
        InstructorAddTaskToStudentToDoListActivity test = new InstructorAddTaskToStudentToDoListActivity();
        int output = test.getRandomInteger();
        int expected = 1293;
        assertEquals(expected,output,.1);
    }
}
```

I am fairly certain some part of the syntax is incorrect, but I cannot find guidance on how to fix it.

The getRandomInteger() function just generates a random integer. It should return false unless I get "lucky" and get the expected number.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at this code:

1.This is using Junit4 & not 5.

2.If you want to use Junit 5, please remove `import org.junit.Test;` & use `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`

3.Please correct [assertEquals](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertEquals-int-int-) by modifying arguments to method. You might need to use only 2 arguments which are `int,int`.

4.Regarding stacktrace error, you can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58057769/method-getmainlooper-in-android-os-looper-not-mocked-still-occuring-even-after-a) if it helps.